# If shiny app users want different ways to select person-level data to visualize, how can multiple `select` control widgets sync together?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

If I have a pretty large (175K rows of individuals) `data.frame` with several columns of useful identifiable information like `FirstName, LastName, UserID, LocationVisited, SSN`, and several columns of data that will be rendered as a table or plot given the user's selection of that person. I want to allow my users to be able to search using any of these fields to whittle down to a selection of ONE row with that person's data.

How can I enable multiple `selectizeInput()` fields to coordinate with each other? Are there any examples that show how each field can work to filter the available options in any other `selectizeInput()` field? For example, with 175K rows, there are going to be hundreds of `FirstName=="Michael"` and/or `LastName=="Smith"`, but the user is obviously going to want to make their own decision about how to search thru the `data.frame` and find the person they want to visualize. It also seems important to include a button that clears the search.

I've looked into this question: [Multiple Text Inputs Search R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445198/multiple-text-inputs-search-r-shiny) , but I thought I would need a `renderUI()` to handle search data that updates with dynamic selectize filtering.

I've done all of my development with `shinydashboard` and I'm trying to keep all of the selection widgets in the sidebar.

This is my code currently and it works alright, but I think it could be faster and far less complicated:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
tagList(uiOutput("patientSelectWidget"), #one ID
        uiOutput("pPID"),   #another type of ID
        uiOutput("pFirstName"),
        uiOutput("pLastName"),
        uiOutput("pFacility"),
        actionButton("clear","Clear Search")) )

server <- function(input, output, session){

  r<-reactiveValues(outcomes=NULL, pii=NULL, prev.b.select=0, searchString="", i=0)
  r$outcomes<-readRDS("MyBigDataFileOfEverything.rds")
  r$pii<-readRDS("MyBigDataFileOfEverything.rds")[, c("SSN", "PATIENT_ID", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "FACILITY")]

  output$patientSelectWidget <- renderUI({
      req(nrow(r$outcomes)>0)
      cat("\nPatient Selection:")
      selectizeInput(inputId = "patient",
                     choices = c("--", sort(r$outcomes$SSN])),
                     label = "Select a Patient by SSN:",
                     multiple = FALSE,selected = "--")
    })
    
    output$pPID <- renderUI({
      req(nrow(r$outcomes)>0)
      cat("\nPatientID Selection:")
      selectizeInput(inputId = "pid", 
                     choices = c("--",sort(r$outcomes$PATIENT_ID)),
                     label = "Choose Patient ID:",
                     multiple = FALSE,selected = "--")
    })
    
    output$pFirstName <- renderUI({
      req(nrow(r$outcomes)>0)
      cat("\nFirstName Selection:")
      p.choices<-c("--",sort(unique(r$outcomes$FIRST_NAME)))
      selectizeInput(inputId = "fname", 
                     choices = p.choices,
                     label = "Search By First Name:",
                     multiple = FALSE,selected = "--")
    })
    
    output$pLastName <- renderUI({
      req(nrow(r$outcomes)>0)
      cat("\nLastName Selection:")
      p.choices<-c("--",sort(unique(r$outcomes$LAST_NAME)))
      selectizeInput(inputId = "lname",
                     choices = p.choices,
                     label = "Search By Last Name:",
                     multiple = FALSE,selected = "--")
    })
    
    output$pFacility <- renderUI({
      req(nrow(r$outcomes)>0)
      cat("\nFacility Selection:")
      p.choices<-c("--",sort(unique(r$outcomes$FACILITY)))
      selectizeInput(inputId = "facility",
                     choices = p.choices,
                     label = "Search By Facility:",
                     multiple = FALSE,selected = "--")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$clear, {
      cat("\nClear Button")
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "patient", 
                           choices = c("--",r$outcomes$SSN), server=TRUE)
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"pid",
                           choices = c("--",r$outcomes$PATIENT_ID), server=TRUE)
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"fname",
                           choices = c("--", sort(unique(r$outcomes$FIRST_NAME))), server=TRUE)
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"lname",
                           choices = c("--", sort(unique(r$outcomes$LAST_NAME))), server=TRUE)
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"facility",
                           choices = c("--", sort(unique(r$outcomes$FACILITY))), server=TRUE)
      r$pii <- r$outcomes[,c("SSN", "PATIENT_ID", "LAST_NAME","FIRST_NAME", "FACILITY")]
    })
    
### Some record keeping while also a hack of a THIN reactive object
    SearchString<-reactive({
      paste0('{"fname" : "',ifelse(input$fname=="--","",input$fname),'" ,',
             '"lname" : "',ifelse(input$lname=="--","",input$lname),'" ,',
             '"facility" : "',ifelse(input$facility=="--","",input$facility),'" ,',
             '"patient" : "',ifelse(input$patient=="--","",input$patient),'" ,',
             '"pid" : "',ifelse(input$pid=="--","",input$pid),'" }')
    })
    
    observeEvent(SearchString(), {
      req(nchar(input$patient)>0)
      cat("\nUpdating SearchCriteria: ",SearchString(),"\n")
      b.select=rep(TRUE,nrow(r$pii)) # Create a TRUE/FALSE selection vector
      if (r$searchString!=SearchString()) { # Test whether there was an update to search
        r.pii<-r$pii  # don't update the reactive object
        if (input$patient!="--") {
          b.select <- which(r$outcomes$SSN==input$patient) # IDs are unique
        } else if (input$pid!="--") {
          b.select <- which(r$outcomes$PATIENT_ID==input$pid) # IDs are unique
        } else {
          cat(" ...subsetting... ")
          r$i<-0 # haven't gotten down to a row yet.
          if (input$fname!="--") {
            b.select <- (b.select & (r.pii$FIRST_NAME==input$fname)) # update T/F vector
          }
          if (input$lname!="--") {
            b.select <- (b.select & (r.pii$LAST_NAME==input$lname)) # update T/F vector
          }
          if (input$facility!="--") { 
            b.select <- (b.select & (r.pii$FACILITY==input$facility)) # update T/F vector
          }
        }
        cat(" ...T/F Vector... ",sum(b.select)) # check 
        if (sum(b.select)==1 | (length(b.select)==1 & b.select[1]>1)) {
          cat("\nUpdate choice to one person")
          index <- ifelse(length(b.select)>1,which(b.select),b.select)
          r$i<-r$outcomes$SSN[index]
          updateSelectizeInput(session,"patient", selected = r$outcomes$SSN[index])
          updateSelectizeInput(session,"pid", selected = r$outcomes$PATIENT_ID[index])
          updateSelectizeInput(session,"fname", selected = r$outcomes$FIRST_NAME[index])
          updateSelectizeInput(session,"lname", selected = r$outcomes$LAST_NAME[index])
          updateSelectizeInput(session,"facility", selected = r$outcomes$FACILITY[index])
          r$searchString<-SearchString()
        } else if (sum(b.select)<nrow(r.pii) & sum(b.select)!=r$prev.b.select) {
          cat("\nUpdate choice to subset of people")
          updateSelectizeInput(session,"patient", choices = c("--", r.pii$SSN[b.select]), server=TRUE) # subset patient SSNs, but don't choose one.
          updateSelectizeInput(session,"pid", choices = c("--", r.pii$PATIENT_ID[b.select]), server=TRUE) # subset patient IDs, but don't choose one.
          if (input$fname=="--") {
            updateSelectizeInput(session,"fname", choices = c("--", unique(r.pii$FIRST_NAME[b.select])), server=TRUE)
          }
          if (input$lname=="--") {
            updateSelectizeInput(session,"lname", choices = c("--", unique(r.pii$LAST_NAME[b.select])), server=TRUE)
          }
          if (input$facility=="--") { 
            updateSelectizeInput(session,"facility", choices = c("--", unique(r.pii$FACILITY[b.select])), server=TRUE)
          }
          r$prev.b.select<-sum(b.select) # Update to new selection
          r$searchString<-SearchString() # Update to newest Search criteria
        }
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: note, I removed any shinydashboard specific code to keep this thin and not muddy the waters

Comment: For a working answer you have to provide sample data. Otherwise only comments. The updateinput methods are slow because need communication back and forth client and server. If you need speed, you have to handle it on the client with javascript.

Comment: Ckeck [selectizeGroupUI](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html).

Comment: This kind of data is a bit troublesome to impute and/or share without imputation, so comments are fine... my apologies to the stackoverflow gods

Comment: @MiguelSuazo, when I use the `updateSelectizeInput(...,server=TRUE)`, I thought that overrides the client end. That's what the documentation suggests. I only need the server-side heavy-lifting when subsetting, not when I've got the final row